# accesing azure database from azure function

Tags: sql-server, azure, xamarin, azure-sql-database

I want to access a database from Xamarin and it looks like a good approach is to create a azure database (free for a while)

So I created an account in azure, I created a DBSQLServer, and a SQLDataBase, I set the admin user and password and opened the firewall as part of the process.

I then created a project with azure function in VS 2019, Created a function that just returns an string in the OkObjectResult, and it works (both visiting the local url and the public (after publishing)).
Then I installed the System.Data.SqlClient Nuget package and then tried to connect to the data base usign admin user and password like this :

```
//did not use "new line"'s in the actual code, included them here for readability. 
using (SqlConnection conn = 
       new SqlConnection("
          Server=tcp:javrsserver.database.windows.net,
          1433;
          Initial Catalog=JaviRS;
          Persist Security Info=False;
          User ID={javirs};Password={-The one set in the azure portal-};
          MultipleActiveResultSets=False;
          Encrypt=True;
          TrustServerCertificate=False;
          Connection Timeout=30;"))
{
   try{
      conn.Open();
   }catch (Exception exc)
   { 
      //here I collect "Login failed for user {javirs}"
      //evntID : 18456
   }
}
```

In theory is just wrong password, but im pretty sure the passowrd is Ok. So I guess is more of some windows weird stuff about user account control ...

Any clue ??

PS: If there is a simplier way to get simple sql into my Xamarin app .. I'm also interested. this Azure thing is an over engineering for what I need and is not free forever..

---

EDIT:

I tried connecting using SQLServver Object Explorer in visual studio, entered the same credentials I entered in the connection string and It does allow me in.. 
[image: sqlServerObjectExlorer successfully logged in]

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm

Comment: isnt SQLLite for local storage? Im trying to do online shared data base

Comment: Yes but you didn't mention that in your question. So you want a cloud database? What's wrong with Azure as a solution?

Comment: Can you please share your error? I have tested just need your error details.  Do you want to insert data from your function to azure sql db?

Comment: the error happens on the conn.Open() and the exception message is the one I wrote "Login failed for user {javirs}". There is a Data field with 5 fields, the only one looking relevant is the code 18546. I googled and is related to login failure. I can also see status 1 (no extra details). And yes, I want to implement CRUD on the database via those functions.. yup

Comment: @Can I share as an answer how I did it with full steps with function and Sql? By the way I have done it with azure function local visual studio project with azure sql db.

Comment: Sure, If following your steps makes it work I will gladly select it as solution :)

Comment: @javirs Take a look. hope will you help you. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it with following steps:

**Azure Sql Script:**

```
CREATE TABLE AzureSqlTable(
    [Id] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
)
GO
```

**Function Class:**

```cs
  public class AzureFunctionV2SqlTableClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string DbOperationType { get; set; }

    }
```

**Azure Function Body:**

```
[FunctionName("FunctionV2SqlConnectionExample")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            //Read Request Body
            var content = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            //Extract Request Body and Parse To Class
            AzureFunctionV2SqlTableClass objFuncV2Sql = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AzureFunctionV2SqlTableClass>(content);

            // variable for global message.
            dynamic validationMessage;


           // Validate param because, I am checking here.

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objFuncV2Sql.FirstName))
            {
                validationMessage = new OkObjectResult("First Name is required!");
                return (IActionResult)validationMessage;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objFuncV2Sql.LastName))
            {
                validationMessage = new OkObjectResult("Last Name is required!");
                return (IActionResult)validationMessage;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objFuncV2Sql.Email))
            {
                validationMessage = new OkObjectResult("Email is required!");
                return (IActionResult)validationMessage;
            }

            //Read database Connection

            var sqlConnection = "Data Source =tcp:sqlserverInstancenNameFromAzurePortal.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=YouDbName;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=ServerUserName;Password=ServerPass;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";

            //Sql Execution Message varible
            dynamic sqlExecutionMessage;
            //Define Db operation Type
            if (objFuncV2Sql.DbOperationType.ToUpper() == "INSERT")
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var text = "INSERT INTO AzureSqlTable VALUES ('" + objFuncV2Sql.FirstName + "', '" + objFuncV2Sql.LastName + "', '" + objFuncV2Sql.Email + "') ";

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(text, conn))
                    {
                        sqlExecutionMessage = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }

                validationMessage = new OkObjectResult(sqlExecutionMessage + " ROW INSERTED");
                return (IActionResult)validationMessage;
            }
            //As we have to return IAction Type So converting to IAction Class Using OkObjectResult We Even Can Use OkResult
            var result = new OkObjectResult("Operation Falid! No Relevant Command Found!");
            return result;
        }
```

**Reference Required:**

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

**Nuget Paackage I used:**

```cs
System.Data.SqlClient(4.6.1)
```

Download from Nuget package manager. See the screen shot below:

[image]

**Post Man Sample:**

```
{
    "FirstName": "Kiron New Sql FunctionV2",
    "LastName":"Kiron New Local Sql",
    "Email":"KironTest@microsoft.com",
    "DbOperationType":"INSERT"
}
```

**Point To Remember:**

1. Follow what I exactly tried to demonstrate here, no engineering
   before make it run
2. Just update the connection string with your `Azure Sql Server
   Credentials`
3. Get rid of {} from password as I did not specified it in my example
   also, While you copy connection string from portal in contain
   `{password}` just omit `{}`
4. If your function encountered error from `Azure Portal SQL Db`
   regarding your Client IP address. In that case just add your Client
   IP like below:

**Step:1**

[image]

**Step:2**
[image]

**Note:** I have just tried to show Insert operation. Hope it will work accordingly.

Comment: Where did you set the User ID=ServerUserName;Password=ServerPass In the connection string??

Comment: These two is from azure SQL Db user login Id and Pass. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/c3beZ53). You can also set that on `local.settings.json` , In short I just showed there

Comment: I exchange the words ServerUserName and ServerPass by the ones that grant me acess to the SQL database editor. Also the same ones I entered in the SQLServer Object Editor in visual studio. And still .. When I try to run the thing I get "Login failed for user '{javirs}'"

Comment: Check your azure sql server allow you or not with this credentials. Seems it's your server issue your. Try creating new one.

Comment: Just copy the connectionstring from your azure portal sql and replace your azure sql user name and password as I have shown in comment screen shot.

Comment: OHMYGOD, I kept the {} around the pasword, I thought it was part of the syntax. I removed the {}. So now it is User ID=javirs,   and it works.
I want to explicit thank you, anyhow, for your detailed answer. THANKS

Comment: I accepted it but, please, include a reference to the {} thing in your text, please

Comment: I have updated that. Though I haven't showed in example that you need to add {}. Anyway good luck.

Comment: you've to consider the initial question was : Why it does not work when I put {} around the Id and the password. The correct answer is: remove the curlies :) But your "guideline" is super useful and I guess future readers will benefit for it being the selected solution

Comment: I'm loving it !

Comment: @javirs Yeah that's why updated it according to your tips. Thanks a lot. Yeah dude Now I understand. My target was to make it run to your code.

Answer (score 0):

The error says:  "Login failed for user {javirs}"

This hints that you included the {} in your user name (and provably in your password. Removing the { and the } will do the trick.

It works now.